# Dota 2 2018 Fantasy Cards

Tags: dota-2

So I purchased a 2018 battle pass a month ago.  My current battle pass level is 218. It's my first time. I don't get the mechanics of the Fantasy feature that has just been enabled today. I opened a lot of player cards and I got most of the players in each team. Can someone explain me the mechanics of this battle pass feature? I tried searching on youtube for explanation but to no avail.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cards will be used when creating a fantasy team for the International 2018.
You will need to select a player for each position and you will get points based on how well the players will perform at the TI (KDA, gpm, xpm, observers planted, runes grabbed, first blood, etc).

Note that you may have the same player on different cards but with different bonuses (for runes, first blood, wards, etc) applied to their score so you need to choose wisely the fantasy team that you will make each day.

This is the same competition mechanic that was used on TI7 or other majors.
You get bonuses for collecting all cards for a team or all gold/silver cards and you can recycle cards to obtain dust (which is used to obtain other cards).